# How to add data in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add my new values in the previous one at a specific id, but every time when I want to add it created data on a new id rather than added with the previous one.

Here is the method of my databasehelper class:

```
     public boolean addalldata(String value1, String value2, String value3) {

    String  previous1 = null,previous2 = null,previous3= null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String myquery = "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE id = 1";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(myquery, null);

    while(res.moveToNext()) {
         previous1 = res.getString(1);
         previous2 = res.getString(2);
         previous3 = res.getString(3);
    }


    contentValues.put(COL_2, value1 + previous1);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, value2 + previous2);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, value3 + previous3);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;}
```

here is the method of mainactivity class

```
        private void AddAllData() {
          btnaddall.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted =       myDb.addalldata(edit1.getText().toString(),
                            edit2.getText().toString(),
                            edit3.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted = true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
    );

}
```

Comment: `insert` creates a new record. you want `update` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public boolean addalldata(String value1, String value2, String value3) {

        String  previous1 = "0",previous2 = "0",previous3= "0";
        long result = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        String myquery = "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE id = 1";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(myquery, null);
        if(res.getCount()>0){
             res.moveToFirst();
             previous1 = res.getString(1);
             previous2 = res.getString(2);
             previous3 = res.getString(3);

             try{
               contentValues.put(COL_2, Integer.parseInt(value1) + Integer.parseInt(previous1));
               contentValues.put(COL_3, Integer.parseInt(value2) + Integer.parseInt(previous2));
               contentValues.put(COL_4, Integer.parseInt(value3) + Integer.parseInt(previous3));
               result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id = ?", new String[]{"1"});
             }catch(Exception e){
               result = -1;
             }


             if (result == -1)
                return false;
             else
                return true;
        }else{
           contentValues.put(COL_2, value1);
           contentValues.put(COL_3, value2);
           contentValues.put(COL_4, value3);
           result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
           if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

}
```

if there is no record in the database then insert a new record using **db.insert** otherwise update the existing record by using **db.update**

Comment: after pasting ur code , in my databasehelper class, it does nt any happen , record 1 not add the new value in the previous one

Comment: may be the id of the record is not 1

Comment: now its just concatenate the new value with the previous one but not added both , i want addition and they are concatenate

Comment: just give me example how do you want to concatenate them

Comment: for example if previous value was 4 , and new value was 3 then result should be 7 not 34

Comment: first let me know that in your text field user can only enter numeric values.

Comment: no they are set as 'text' but i entering only numeric values

Comment: then set input type to number in your xml code. and give me few minutes i will update my code..

Answer (score 0):

try res.moveToFirst().
This will move your cursor to first position so that furthur checking starts from the first row.